# How do I add javascript to an individual tumblr blog post?

Tags: javascript, tumblr

The similar questions that have accepted answers no longer work. Please actually test before giving an answer. I've tried clicking on the "HTML" setting to edit the HTML. I put `<script> alert('test') </script>`. When I save it, Tumblr just puts the script inside a `<p></p>`.

I'm wanting to showcase Highcharts and d3 graphs in my posts. I need javascript for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't add scripts straight into a page template. You have two other options. You can create custom js in the bottom of your template and then only fire it for that page if it meets certain criteria (ie a classname length or suchlike). Or you can do the same with a remotely hosted file. Again this would need to be linked into your template and then only fire for the particular page you want. I've worked on both solutions in the past.

Comment: Actually you can link to an online js resource/file in a single page. See here  https://imgur.com/a/9j1VkzZ